# Azure for Students (Imagine) vs. Cloud Shell

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-cloud-shell

Our school has an Imagine subscription, which allows lecturers and students to sign up for Azure for Students.

Now we would like to create a HTML5 web service as described in this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-web-get-started-html

The problem is, that we can not use Cloud Shell, because it keeps asking for Microsoft.Storage, which is apparently not included in Azure for Students?

How could we resolve this problem and succeed with the above mentioned "HTML5 web app tutorial" with our "Azure for Students accounts"?

Best regards, András

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud Shell is a convinient feature, but not a requierment to go through the sample.

You can install the Azure CLI localy to your machine:
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli

Once you have the CLI installed, you can run the same commands locally from your machine. This does not require you to have a storage account.

Answer (score 0):

Bryan is correct in his posting above, you should be able to complete your web apps scenario without Cloud Shell.

That being said, unfortunately the [Imagine subscription](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0144p/) is not enabled to provision cost-incurring resources. As a result you are correct you cannot access Cloud Shell without the pre-req of an Azure File share. However you can create an [Azure free trial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/offers/ms-azr-0044p/) that provides credits to provision cost-incurring resources and thus would enable you access to Cloud Shell.